# Riot.mount(*) doesnt have any effect

Tags: javascript, html, riot.js

Simple problem here but unfortunately can't solve. As mentioned in the title, I can't get Riot to show the contents of its custom tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <hello></hello>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/riot/riot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> riot.mount('*'); </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello.js"></script>
</body>
```

The hello.js is the generated js, here is its code:

```
riot.tag('hello', '<div> asdasd </div>', function(opts) {
});
```

And here is its HTML:

```
<hello>
    <div>
        asdasd
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
</hello>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't mount your tag before declaring it.

You need to do in this order:

Include riot:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/riot/riot.min.js"></script>
```

Declare your tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello.js"></script>
```

Mount your declared tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> riot.mount('*'); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Woops. Scrap that. Moved the hello.js just below the riot.min.js and it worked. Apparently placing that there and above the mount is critical.